# Minecraft Won't Let Me Break Any Blocks At All

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on minecraft, I made sure that my game mode is creative, so I don't need to hold to break blocks. Yet, I am unable to break ANYTHING. Not even DIRT. I can still place blocks, I just can't break them. Can't break any blocks in survival either..... I also cannot kill mobs. And I'm most definatly not in adventure mode! Please Help! It's been going on for weeks!

Comment: Please provide more details. Right now it sounds just like you've got a problem with left-clicking, which for all we know could be a bad mouse. Is there a stutter during attempts to break blocks/kill mobs? Can mobs kill you? Is it performing especially slowly?  Are you holding the mouse button down, rather than just clicking once? Any and all relevant details will help, and can help distinguish your question from a very similarly-sounding one that Unionhawk has linked.

Comment: It could also be that your controls have been mis-mapped. Open up the controls menu and see if "attack/break" has been mapped away from the left mouse button.